# use of internal package github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-sdk-for-go-samples/internal/config not allowed

Tags: azure, go, azure-vm

I am trying to call GetVM from azure-sdk-for-go-samples/compute and when I am trying to build project it is showing the below error

```
 use of internal package github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-sdk-for-go-samples/internal/config not allowed
test.go:17:2: use of internal package github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-sdk-for-go-samples/internal/iam not allowed
```

I am using Go version : 1.14.3

Note: I am cloning the repo in $GOPATH/src/githhub.com directory .

Comment: The error message is 100% clear and spot on: "use of internal package [...] not allowed". There is nothing more to know here.

Comment: But this is external package still showing this kind of error. [https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-sdk-for-go-samples] I also have search for same errors. @Volker

Comment: github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-sdk-for-go-samples is **not** a package so it cannot show this error message. If you need help you must provide much more information in much greater detail.

Answer (score 1):

internal packages are specifically marked as not for use outside of that program or package, and therefore cannot be imported. See: https://golang.org/doc/go1.4#internalpackages